# Convert Json to a java object

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

What is the way to generate a Java object with get and set methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

That link helps generate the Java object format based on the GSON you feed in. Just make sure you set the settings exactly as you need it. As always, it's not a good idea to just copy-paste generated code, but it might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a java bean with properties maching the JSON key's, from that point since you already have a reader its a simple as

```
YourObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, YourObject.class);
```

UPDATE

With respect to your comment, when you don't want or can't create a bean it usually boils down to parsing JSON to map. GSON (afaik) doesn't have a built-in for this, but its not hard to build a method that will traverse GSON's objects. You have an example in this blog

http://itsmyviewofthings.blogspot.it/2013/04/jsonconverter-code-that-converts-json.html

As you seem to be open to alternatives, take a look at Jackson as well (the two libs are the de-facto standard in JAVA).

With jackson you don't have to create a bean to support deserialization, e.g.

```
    String json = "{\"id\":\"masterslave\"}";
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //convert JSON string to Map
    map = mapper.readValue(json, 
    new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
```

Comment: Ok MasterSlave, but I would like to know if there is any other way to avoid create a java bean programmatically. For instance if a Json messagge has 1000 field I must spend a lot of time to create the bean.

Comment: Don't edit OP with your _own_ comments. Add any comment/additional details to your _own_ post.